# Loop thru directory and return directory name

Tags: bash

Im trying to loop thru a directory (non recursive) and I only want to list the directory name, not the path.

```
find /dir/* -type d -prune -exec basename {} \;
```

This returns a list of directories in the dir and it works.

```
folder 1
this is folder2
```

And I want to loop thru these so I did:

```
for i in $(/dir/* -type d -prune -exec basename {} \;)
do
    echo ${i}
done
```

But the for loop loops thru each word and not row. which results in this:

```
folder
1
this
is
folder2
```

I know there is a lot of threads on this but I haven't found anyone that works for me. Especally with spaces in the name.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
find /dir/* -type d -prune -exec basename {} \; | while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Nice, it seems to work. I'll work with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through directory names then you can use;

```
( cd /dir && for f in */; do echo "$f"; done )
```

In case you want to loop thru the *find results* only then better way to do that is:

```
while read -r f; do
    echo "$f"
done < <(find /dir/ -type d -prune -exec basename '{}' \;)
```

This is preferred since it avoids spawning a subshell (though `find -exec` will create subshells).

Answer (score 0):

`find /dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf %f`